# Regular expression to extract link text from anchor tag

Tags: php, regex

i want to get the word Asarum in the below line:

```
 <A HREF="http://www.getty.edu/vow/TGNFullDisplay?find=&place=&nation=&english=Y&subjectid=1062783">Asarum</A>
```

i tried with:

```
preg_replace('/<a.*?>/i', '', $link);
preg_replace('/<\/a>/i', '', $link);
echo $link;
```

but it doesn't work. nothing was cut out.

could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the result:

```
$link = preg_replace('/<a.*?>/i', '', $link);
$link = preg_replace('/<\/a>/i', '', $link);
echo $link;
```

Comment: strange. i have never done that before and it seemed to work...maybe i am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Fastest (probably - not tested):

```
$t = substr($link, strpos($link, '>') + 1, -4);
```

Clearest:

```
$t = strip_tags($link);
```

Basic strip tags w/ regex:

```
$t = preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $link);
```

Comment: I should note, this only works if the string you're given only contains that single HTML element. If you were trying to pick an anchor element out of a larger fragment of HTML, you'd want DouweM's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code, to match the text to a specific regex, instead of replacing everything else:

```
preg_match('/<a.*?>(.+?)<\/a>/i', $link, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` will now contain the text you're looking for.

Comment: are you sure? i just want to get the text within the tags, not the whole element which seems to be that im getting with your code.

Comment: My code should give you just the text inside the `<a>` tag... Have you tried `print_r($matches)` to see what's exactly in there?

Comment: +1 because your solution does work, though with the given input you could get away with `'/>([^<]+)/'` as the pattern.