# Extract anchor tag link text using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to extract the link text from something like the line below using PowerShell.

```
<a href="javascript:showPopupWindow('catdesc.jsp?catnum=20')">Entertainment</a>, <a href="javascript:showPopupWindow('catdesc.jsp?catnum=5')">Intimate Apparel/Swimsuit</a>, and <a href="javascript:showPopupWindow('catdesc.jsp?catnum=92')">Suspicious</a>
```

I've tried the following but it's only matching the first result and is including the `>` and `<` which I don't want. I'm sure it's an issue with the Regex but I don't know it well enough to see what's wrong. Note the string above is `$result.categorization`

```
$result.categorization -match '(\>(.*?)\<)'
```

This returns

```
Name,Value
2,Entertainment                                                                            
1,>Entertainment<
0,>Entertainment<
```

I want to return

```
Name,Value
2,Suspicious                                                                            
1,Intimate Apparel/Swimsuit
0,Entertainment
```

I also tried the Regex listed [Regular expression to extract link text from anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301695/regular-expression-to-extract-link-text-from-anchor-tag) but that didn't match on anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where the headers and numbers in the output come from, but here's a solution that extracts the link texts from the single-line input exactly as specified:

```
$str = @'
<a href="javascript:showPopupWindow('catdesc.jsp?catnum=20')">Entertainment</a>, <a href="javascript:showPopupWindow('catdesc.jsp?catnum=5')">Intimate Apparel/Swimsuit</a>, and <a href="javascript:showPopupWindow('catdesc.jsp?catnum=92')">Suspicious</a>
'@

$str -split ', and |, ' -replace '.*?>([^<]*).*', '$1'
```

- `$str -split ', and |, '` splits the input line into individual `<a>` elements.
- `-replace` then operates on each `<a>` element individually:

  - `'.*?>([^<]*).*'` matches the *entire* line, but captures only the link text in the one and only capture group, `(...)`.
  - Replacement text `$1` then replaces the entire line with what the capture group matched, i.e., effectively only returning the link text.

---

As for what you tried:

`-match` never extracts *part* of its input - it returns a *Boolean* indicating whether a match was found with a *scalar* LHS, or a filtered sub-array of matching items with an *array* as the LHS.

That said, the automatic `$Matches` variable does contain information about what parts matched, but only with a *scalar* LHS.

`'(\>(.*?)\<)'` contains two nested capture groups that match literal `>` followed by any number of characters (matching non-greedily), followed by literal `<`.
It is the *inner* capture group that would capture the link text.
However:

- There is no need for the *outer* capture group.
- `>` and `<` do *not* need `\`-escaping in a regular expression (although it does no harm).

Comment: @YEMyslf: Glad to hear it; my pleasure.